# What breaks down in linear algebra over the rings (or commutative rings)?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $R$ be a ring (with $1$). Last night, I was trying to prove that $M_{n}(R)$ (the ring of $n \times n$ matrices over $R$) is a ring. As I have done in my previous linear algebra course (which was over $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$), for the proof of painful associativity and distributivities of matrix ring, I looked for isomorphism between $M_{n}(R)$ and $\text{End}_{R}(R^{n})$ as the latter is eaiser to be seen as a ring. However, the construction of this map that I knew from linear algebra as follow was not necessarily an isomorphism unless $R$ is commutative:

- $F:\text{End}_{R}(R^{n}) \rightarrow M_{n}(R)$ defined by $\varphi \rightarrow (a_{ij})$ where $\varphi(e_{j}) = \sum_{i}a_{ij}e_{i}$ where $e_{j}$ is the unity of $j$th summand of $R^{n}$ when we consider multiplication or $\text{End}_{R}(R^{n})$ as $\circ$ where $(\varphi \circ \theta)(x) = \varphi(\theta(x))$ whenever $x \in R$.

What worked as an isomorphism is as follows:

- $F^{t}:\text{End}_{R}(R^{n}) \rightarrow M_{n}(R)$ defined by $\varphi \rightarrow F(\varphi)^{t}$ where we understand multiplication of $\text{End}_{R}(R^{n})$ as $(x)\varphi \theta = \theta(\varphi(x))$ whenever $x \in R$.

Just like this example, I wonder how many elementary mechanics break down when it comes to linear algebra over a ring or a commutative ring (with $1$).

(For an example regarding commutative ring $R$, see that invertible matrices in $M_{n}(R)$ are the ones whose determinants are units not just nonzero.)

Again, rings that I consider allow unity. I also want to require answers to be as "sharp" as possible, so if something does not work even when we assume that $R$ is integral domain, I  am asking that to be specified. No require for rigorous proofs as this question is aimed for my own learning, but some nice examples are always appreciated (but not required). Thanks.

Comment: Should this be community wiki since it asks for a list of examples?

Comment: Use instead the [opposite ring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opposite_ring) of the ring of matrices which turns out to be isomorphic to the ring of matrices over the opposite ring of $R$.

Comment: @YACP Yes. I see that can also work.

Comment: @K.Stm Thanks for suggestion, but note that examples are not main but optional in this question.

Comment: @GilYoung I think he wants answers like "maximal linearly independent systems aren't necessarily bases anymore" and optionally examples like "e.g. in $ℤ$ over $ℤ$ the system $\{2\}$ is maximally linearly independent, yet no basis".